# Could not import PILLOW_VERSION from PIL

Tags: python, anaconda, python-imaging-library

While importing, Python (Anaconda) gives the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'PILLOW_VERSION' from 'PIL'
```

I tried removing `pillow` and then `conda install` but the error persists.

Comment: Use PIL.__version__ instead.

Comment: @abhilb I am importing torchvision, which is calling the PILLOW_VERSION

Comment: Ok. then probably check the version of PIL that you have and the version needed for torchvision. There might be a mismatch. PILLOW_VERSION is deprecated in the latest version of PIL

Comment: probably you will have to downgrade the pillow version

Comment: Or upgrade torchvision.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Pillow 7.0.0 removed `PILLOW_VERSION`, you should use `__version__` in your own code instead.

- https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deprecations.html#pillow-version-constant

---

Edit (2020-01-16):

If using torchvision, this has been fixed in [v0.5.0](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/releases/tag/v0.5.0). To fix:

1. Require `torchvision>=0.5.0`
2. If Pillow was temporarily pinned, remove the pin

---

Old info (2020-01-09):

If using torchvision, there is a release planned this week (week 2, 2020) to fix it:

- https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/1712#issuecomment-570286349

The options are:

- wait for the new torchvision release
- use the master version of torchvision (eg. `pip install -U git+https://github.com/pytorch/vision`)
- install torchvision from a nightly, which also requires a pytorch from a nightly version
- or install Pillow<7 (eg. `pip install "pillow<7"`)

Answer (score 25):

Downgrade pillow if you don't need latest features

```
pip uninstall pillow
pip install "pillow<7"
```

Or for anaconda,

```
conda install -c anaconda "pillow<7"
```

Comment: Or `pip install "pillow<7"`, as 6.2.2 (and 7.0.0) contains security fixes:  https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/releasenotes/6.2.2.html

Comment: For Anaconda user, it is `conda install -c anaconda pillow=6.1`.

Comment: for torch compatibility this works great

Answer (score 11):

I have solved by modifying `functional.py` and `__init__.py` which are mentioned in error message.[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJZpE.png).

Modify `from PIL import Image, ImageOps, ImageEnhance, PILLOW_VERSION` to `from PIL import Image, ImageOps, ImageEnhance, __version__` in `functional.py` approx line number 5.

Modify `PILLOW_VERSION = __version__ = _version.__version__` to `__version__ = __version__ = _version.__version__` in `__init__.py`, approx line no 22.

File path:

- `functional.py`:`C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\torchvision\transforms\functional.py`
- `__init__.py`:`C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\PIL\__init__.py`

Comment: this worked for me... i just replaced `PILLOW_VERSION ` by `__version__ `  in `functional.py` at : `Your_File_Path\Lib\site-packages\torchvision\transforms\functional.py` and then there were no errors.

Comment: this worked for me. Nothing else worked. One of those 2 hour nightmares.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me as well. I only needed to modify `functional.py` for `torchvision.__version__=0.2.2`, `PIL.__version__=9.0.1`, and Python 3.9.12 (anaconda3)

Comment: same here, needed to modify the functional.py part only

Comment: here are the commands i did to make this change bc i couldnt access files directly (note the exclamation points at the start of each line bc i did it in jupyter, remove if youre just in the command line):

`!sed -i "s/from PIL import Image, ImageOps, ImageEnhance, PILLOW_VERSION/from PIL import Image, ImageOps, ImageEnhance, __version__/g" /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/torchvision/transforms/functional.py
!sed -i "s/PILLOW_VERSION = __version__ = _version.__version__/__version__ = PILLOW_VERSION = _version.__version__/g" /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/PIL/__init__.py`

Answer (score 6):

- Currently using torchvision==0.4.2 and this solved my problem.
- Downgrade your pillow to 6.1 and restart your Jupyter notebook.

  **Use this**

  `conda install pillow=6.1`

Answer (score 1):

I found one another good solution:
Install Pillow-SIMD instead of Pillow.

> Pillow-SIMD is "following" Pillow. Pillow-SIMD versions are 100%
>   compatible drop-in replacements for Pillow of the same version.
>   SIMD stands for "single instruction, multiple data" and its essence is
>   in performing the same operation on multiple data points
>   simultaneously by using multiple processing elements.

Homepage:
https://github.com/uploadcare/pillow-simd

Benchmarks:
https://python-pillow.org/pillow-perf/

Install instructions:

```
$ pip uninstall pillow
$ CC="cc -mavx2" pip install -U --force-reinstall pillow-simd
```

**I checked: it has not such error and works on Pytorch/Torchvision.**

You don't need to downgrade packages or change source code.

Answer (score 0):

This is my fix to the error

```
Error: Could not import PILLOW_VERSION from PIL
OS: Linux 18.0 (LUBUNTU)
Python: 3.6
```

Resolved the issue by downgrading pillow:

```
pillow: 7.0.0-py36hb39fc2d_0 --> 6.1.0-py36h34e0f95_0
command: conda install pillow=6.1
```

Answer (score 0):

The less painful way that worked for me is using `alias`

`from PIL import __version__ as PILLOW_VERSION`

Why?

> Pillow is forked from PIL 1.1.7
> VERSION was removed in Pillow 6.0.0
> PILLOW_VERSION was removed in Pillow 9.0.0
> Use __version__ instead

When you use some older packages, they try to import `PILLOW_VERSION` which is no longer available. So you'll need to use `alias`.